# Overload resolution for non-member functions (/non-constructor contexts) with std::initializer_list argument(s)

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, overload-resolution

*(All ISO Standard references below refer to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/), and all example program results are consistent over GCC and Clang for C++11, C++14 and C++17*)

Consider the following example:

```
#include <initializer_list>

// Denote as A.
void f(float) {}

// Denote as B.
void f(std::initializer_list<int>) {}

int main() {
    // Denote call as C1.  
    f(1.5F);    // Overload resolution picks A (trivial).

    // Denote call as C2.
    f({1.5F});  // Overload resolution picks B (and subsequently fails; narrowing).

    return 0;
}
```

which results in the call C2 picking overload B as best viable function, followed by a failure due to narrowing in list initialization (governed by [[dcl.init.list]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#7)):

> ```
> error: type 'float' cannot be narrowed to 'int' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
> ```

## Question

- Why does the `f({1.5F});` *function call* find `void f(std::initializer_list<int>)` to be the unique best viable function, ranked as a better match than `void f(float)`? Afaics this conflicts with [[over.ics.list]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.list#4) and [[over.ics.list]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.list#9) (see details below).

I'm looking for references to the relevant standard passages.

Note that I am aware of the special rules regarding overload resolution for *list initialization* (constructor overloading) and `std::initializer_list<>` (and the various SO questions on this topic), where `std::initializer_list<>` is strongly preferred, as governed by [[over.match.list]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.list#1). However, afaics, this does not apply here (or, if I'm wrong, at the very least arguably conflicts with the standard examples shown in [[over.ics.list]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.list#4)).

---

## Details and investigation of my own

For both C1 and C2 calls above, overload resolution is applied as specified in [[over.call.func]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.call.func) (as per [[over.match]/2.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match#2.1) and [[over.match.call]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.call)), particularly [[over.call.func]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.call.func#3), and the set of *candidate functions* for both calls is:

```
candidate_functions(C1) = { void f(float),
                            void f(std::initializer_list<int>) }

candidate_functions(C2) = { void f(float),
                            void f(std::initializer_list<int>) }
```

and the *argument list* in each call is the same as the *expression-list* in the call.

As per [[over.match.viable]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.viable#2) and [[over.match.viable]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.viable#3), the set of *viable functions* is the same as the *candidate functions* for both calls:

```
viable_functions(C1) = { void f(float),
                         void f(std::initializer_list<int>) }

viable_functions(C2) = { void f(float),
                         void f(std::initializer_list<int>) }
```

### Best viable functions

As per [[over.match.best]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.best#1), in short terms, the *best viable function* for a given function call, here specifically a single-argument call (with no special cases for the *viable functions* of each call), is the viable function that, for the single argument, has the best *implicit conversion sequence* from the single argument to the single parameter of the respective viable function.

#### C1: Best viable function

The call `f(1.5F)` has an identity standard conversion (no conversion) and thus an *exact match* for A (as per [[over.ics.scs]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.scs#3)) and A can be (trivially and) non-ambiguously chosen as the best viable function.

```
best_viable_function(C1) = void f(float)
```

#### C2: Best viable function

Afaics, ranking the implicit conversion sequences of the call `f({1.5F})` towards viable candidates is governed by [[over.ics.list]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.list), as per [[over.ics.list]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.list#1):

> When an argument is an initializer list ([dcl.init.list]), it is not an expression and special rules apply for converting it to a parameter type.

***Matching C2 towards A***

For matching towards A where the single parameter is of the fundamental `float` type, [[over.ics.list]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.list#9) and particularly [[over.ics.list]/9.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.list#9.1) applies [**emphasis** mine]:

> Otherwise, if the parameter type is not a class:
>
> - (9.1) if the initializer list **has one element** that is not itself an initializer list, the implicit conversion sequence is the
>     one required **to convert the element to the parameter type**;
>     [ *Example*:
>
>   ```
>   void f(int);
>   f( {'a'} );             // OK: same conversion as char to int
>   f( {1.0} );             // error: narrowing
>   ```
>
>   — *end example* ]
> - [...]

This arguably means that the implicit conversion sequence for matching the call `f({1.5F}}` to `f(float)` is the same conversion sequence as `float` to `float`; i.e., identity conversion and subsequently an exact match. However, as per the example above, there must be some flaw in my logic here as the call C2 doesn't even result in an ambiguous best viable function.

***Matching C2 towards B***

For matching towards B where the single parameter [[over.ics.list]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.list#4) applies [**emphasis** mine]:

> Otherwise, if the parameter type is `std​::​initializer_­list<X>` and
>   all the elements of the initializer list can be implicitly converted
>   to `X`, **the implicit conversion sequence is the worst conversion
>   necessary to convert an element of the list to `X`**, or if the
>   initializer list has no elements, the identity conversion. This
>   conversion can be a user-defined conversion even in the context of a
>   call to an initializer-list constructor. [ Example:
>
> ```
> void f(std::initializer_list<int>);
> f( {} );                // OK: f(initializer_­list<int>) identity conversion
> f( {1,2,3} );           // OK: f(initializer_­list<int>) identity conversion
> f( {'a','b'} );         // OK: f(initializer_­list<int>) integral promotion
> f( {1.0} );             // error: narrowing
>
> [...]
> ```
>
> — end example ]

In this example, the implicit conversion sequence is thus *the worst conversion* necessary to convert the single `float` element of the list to `int`, which is a *conversion* ranked standard conversion sequence ([[over.ics.scs]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.scs#3)), particularly a narrowing conversion as per [[conv.fpint]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.fpint#1).

***Best viable function***

According to my own interpretation of the standard passages as per above, the best viable function should be the same as for the C1 call,

```
best_viable_function(C2) = void f(float) ?
```

but I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: Note that this was never intended to be a self-answering question, and I somewhat depressingly found the relevant standard section only after finishing writing and posting the question :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### List-initialization sequences: special case ranking when one sequence converts to `std::initializer_list`

[[over.ics.rank]/3.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.rank#3.1) applies for this case, and takes precedence over the other rules of [[over.ics.rank]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.rank#3) [**emphasis** mine]:

> List-initialization sequence `L1` is **a better conversion sequence** than
>   list-initialization sequence `L2` **if**
>
> - (3.1.1) **`L1` converts to `std​::​initializer_­list<X>`** for some `X` **and `L2` does not**, or, if not that
> - (3.1.2) [...]
>
> **even if one of the other rules in this paragraph would otherwise apply**. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> void f1(int);                                 // #1
> void f1(std::initializer_list<long>);         // #2
> void g1() { f1({42}); }                       // chooses #2
>
> void f2(std::pair<const char*, const char*>); // #3
> void f2(std::initializer_list<std::string>);  // #4
> void g2() { f2({"foo","bar"}); }              // chooses #4
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

meaning that [[over.ics.rank]/3.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.rank#3.2) and  [[over.ics.rank]/3.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.rank#3.3), covering distinguishing implicit conversion sequences by means of standard conversion sequences and user defined conversion sequences, respectively, does not apply, which in turn means  [[over.ics.list]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.list#4) and [[over.ics.list]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.list#9) will not be used to rank the implicit conversion sequences when comparing the best match out of *"C2 calls A"* vs *"C2 calls B"*.

---

### This very topic was a defect in C++11 and C++14

It's not surprising that these conversions may come as counter-intuitive, and that the rules governing them are complicated. In the original C++11 and C++14 ISO standard releases, the call `f({1.5F});` actually had ambiguous ranking rules w.r.t. the best viable function, which was covered in [CWG Defect Report 1589](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1589) [***emphasis*** mine]:

> #### 1589. Ambiguous ranking of list-initialization sequences
>
> **Section**: 16.3.3.2  [over.ics.rank]
>   **Status**: CD4
>   **Submitter**: Johannes Schaub
>   **Date**: 2012-11-21
>
> [Moved to DR at the November, 2014 meeting.]
>
> The interpretation of the following example is unclear in the current
>   wording:
>
> ```
> void f(long);
> void f(initializer_list<int>);
> int main() { f({1L});
> ```
>
> The problem is that ***a list-initialization sequence can also be a
>   standard conversion sequence***, depending on the types of the elements
>   and the type of the parameter, ***so more than one bullet*** in the list
>   in 16.3.3.2 [over.ics.rank] paragraph 3 ***applies***:
>
> > [...]
>
> These bullets give opposite results for the example above, and there
>   is implementation variance in which is selected.
>
> [...]
>
> **Proposed resolution (June, 2014):**
>
> This issue is resolved by the resolution of issue
>   [1467](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1467).

[CWG Defect Report 1467](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1467) finally resolved also DR 1589, particularly adding the relevant part quoted from [over.ics.rank]/3 above [***emphasis*** mine]:

> #### 1467. List-initialization of aggregate from same-type object
>
> [...]
>
> **Proposed resolution (June, 2014):**
>
> [...]
>
> 6. Move the final bullet of 16.3.3.2 [over.ics.rank] paragraph 3 to the beginning of the list and change it as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> ***even if one of the other rules in this paragraph would otherwise apply.*** [*Example*: ...  — *end example*]
>
> This resolution also resolves issues 1490, 1589, 1631, 1756, and 1758.

Compilers such as GCC and Clang has since back-ported DR 1467 to earlier standards (C++11 and C++14).